# how to convert element from int to str in python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

how to convert element from int to str in python notebook

for example:

when run this cell in python notebook:  train_dataset.StateHoliday.unique()
I got: array(['0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 0], dtype=object)

I want to get: array(['0', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)

just wondering how to achieve that, thanks.

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Turn the list elem into string

`list(map(str, my_list))`
This will allow you to make both `'0'` & `0` strings

## 2. Remove the duplicates

You are doing this by creating a dictionary with `dict.fromkeys()`. By definition dict cannot have duplicates, it will automatically remove them.

Then turn it back to a list with `list()`

```py
test = ['0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 0]

## Turns every element to string
var_2 = list(map(str, test))

## Remove duplicates
res = list(dict.fromkeys(var_2))

print('Final result : ', res)
```

Comment: @apple, was this answer useful ? Did you manage to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess train_dataset.StateHoliday is a pandas series object. If so following code will work

```py
train_dataset.StateHoliday.astype(str).unique()
```

`astype(str)` will convert all elements to string